# Ruby - everything evaluates to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

According to the literature I have been reading online, everything evaluates to true in Ruby except false and nil. I am trying to find out what benefits this may have? Thanks

Comment: What benefits *doesn't* it have? It's just a language design choice.

Answer (score 7):

I will sum  this advantage up in checking if the user input a value.

PHP:

```php
if($somevalue !== null) { # '' and '0' are falsy.
```

Ruby:

```
if somevalue
```

Answer (score 5):

It makes the language's concept of truth very simple — the only things that are considered "false" are things that do logically represent a "no" answer: false itself and nil, which represents the concept of "nothingness". In a language like Ruby, I find it hard to argue for making more values falsy unless it's just to make things feel more familiar for people experienced in other languages.

(Incidentally, I also think C's model of truth is very simple: If something is equivalent to zero, it's false. But in Ruby, where we deal mainly in objects rather than numbers, this would make `false` truthy!)

Answer (score 1):

It makes most logic statements easier to read. (And write, but I consider that of lesser importance.)

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Ruby is an object. [Here's a decent read](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/true-false-and-nil-objects-in-ruby/).

Comment: That doesn't really help, though; `false` is also an object--so how does everything being an object answer the question? (Actually asking--I could just be missing something obvious.)